# Ipython Widgets (how to make a timer)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython-parallel, ipywidgets

I made this timer widget that works the way I want, but it locks up the notebook so I can't execute other code cells at the same time.

Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

**Any ideas for getting the widget to execute in the background?**

In case it helps, here is the code that makes the above widget:

```python
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
from traitlets import Unicode, validate
import time

class Timer(widgets.DOMWidget):
    _view_name = Unicode('HelloView').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module = Unicode('hello').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module_version = Unicode('0.1.0').tag(sync=True)
    value = Unicode('00:00:00').tag(sync=True)

    def timeit(self, b, limit=180):
        #display(self)
        hours = 0
        mins = 0
        secs = 0
        for i in range(1,(limit*60+1)):
            if i%60 == 0:
                if i%3600 == 0:
                    secs = 0
                    mins = 0
                    hours += 1
                else:
                    secs = 0
                    mins += 1
            else:
                secs += 1
            time.sleep(1)
            self.value = '{hour:02}:{minute:02}:{second:02}'.format(hour=hours,minute=mins,second=secs)


def display_timer(timer):
    button = widgets.Button(description="Start Timer", button_style='info')
    display(button)
    display(timer)
    button.on_click(timer.timeit)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. Read this [doc](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Asynchronous.html#Updating-a-widget-in-the-background) for details.

You use the `threading` library to make your update function (in my case the timer that updates every second) run separately so you can still execute other code cells.

Also, I tried doing a couple `%%timeit` 's on simple test functions like this:

`[x*=x for i in range(20)]`

And it looks like having this timer widget running in the background didn't cause a significant increase in execution time.